# how to find data from list in excel using any function?

Tags: excel

[image: Here is a screenshot of my excel]

In above excel there is one list of data on left side `B2:B12`.

In `E4` cell, the user can enter data which they want like from (if to Vs1) then if-vs1 and I want complete data from if to vs1 like IF-VVS1-VVS2-VS2-VS1.

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think you  can use VLookup for this as it will return the first match it finds. You will need a more complex function for this I believe.

Comment: can you please help me on this @BarryThomas?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it myself. If you search for something like Vlookup return multiple matches, you may find something that can. Sorry.

Comment: does it always stat with IF? or can it start anywhere in the list c3-c13?

Comment: it can start from anywhere in the list c3-c13 @dgorti